# Can we have different classpath location from one maven dependency to another?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm working on an app composed of two java project
Project A and Project B.

In project B pom.xml, i have indicated project A as a dependency.

In a spring config file for project A, i use propertyPlaceholders to load values from a property file.

This is the spring-jBPMConfig.xml file defined in project A:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">



             <bean id="dataSource"
                 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

                 <property name="driverClassName" value="${jBPM.database.driver.class.name}" />
                 <property name="url" value="${jBPM.database.url}" />
                 <property name="username" value="${jBPM.database.user.name}" />
                 <property name="password" value="${jBPM.database.user.password}" />
            </bean>


             <bean name="propertyPlaceholder"
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
              <property name="locations">
                 <list>
                     <value>classpath:/**/global.properties</value>
                 </list>
              </property>
          </bean>
```

As you can see i want to load global.properties file from anywhere under src/main/resources.

This configuration works in unit tests for project A, so the values from global.properties are well loaded wherever global.properties is, under src/main/resources.

Weirdly when i run project B within what project A is called, compilation fails while complaining that project A could not be initialized due to the fact that the variables used in project A spring config file could not be resolved. And this is because the global.properties file is not found in the classpath, by the way  the placeholderConfigurer is defined.

This is the main cause of the failure:

```
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jBPM.database.driver.class.name' in string value "${jBPM.database.driver.class.name}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:206)
    ... 77 more
```

do project A and B could possibly have different classpath location?

Can someone help me understand what is happening?

Note that the problem is solved if i mention a hard fix path like classpath:service/global.properties in propertyplaceholderconfigurer. But i do not want a fix location

Comment: Can you please add the entire application context xml file for both the projects  and also the stacktrace of the error that you encountered?

Comment: i have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You say that A is a dependency of B. What is the location of the properties, and are they added to the jar? (they might be visible at runtime of A, but not packaged. In that case, B does not have access to these properties)

Comment: the .properties is under src/main/resources/service/<--here in project A, when packaging project A, properties files are added to its jar.  I note that the problem is solved if i mention a hard fix path like   classpath:service/global.properties   in propertyplaceholderconfigurer. But i do not want a fix location